# android cannot find corresponding jni function

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've followed [here](https://github.com/GerardSoleCa/Robosodium) and I've added the .so files to my android project. Loaded the library and the project runs.

Now I want to use a function of the library. I tried like this in my `MainActivity`:

```
public final static native int crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt(byte[] jarg1, int[] jarg2, byte[] jarg3, int jarg4, byte[] jarg5, int jarg6, byte[] jarg7, byte[] jarg8, byte[] jarg9);
```

Android gives me that he cannot find the corresponding JNI function.

The so files are in jniLibs in the right architecture map.

Has this something to do with my packagename that he tries to find it in my package instead of in the so library?

When I run this I get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int be.example.libtest.MainActivity.crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt(byte[], int[], byte[], int, byte[], int, byte[], byte[], byte[]) (tried Java_be_example_libtest_MainActivity_crypto_1aead_1chacha20poly1305_1encrypt and Java_be_example_libtest_MainActivity_crypto_1aead_1chacha20poly1305_1encrypt___3B_3I_3BI_3BI_3B_3B_3B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that **Robosodium** uses **Swig** to generate wrapper. In this case there should be also some automatically generated Java files in `src/main/java/org/abstractj/kalium` that need to be added to your project as well. All native calls should be made using methods provided in that classes.

Comment: Do I need to copy the folder org to my main/java or do I need to make the files in my own package and then copy the code from their files?

Comment: Indeed you need to copy the org folder to your own project under java.

Answer (score -1):

Create folders with names of "armeabi" and "armeabi-v7a" in libs folder of your project and place your ".so" file into that both folders and clean the project and run it.

Comment: I already have that. I have them in bot libs and jniLibs folder.